# python libcloud create VM inside vAPP

Tags: python, linux, vcloud-director-rest-api, libcloud

i am able to create a node(vAPP) in cloud using libcloud, however the API does not mention a way to create a VM inside an existing vAPP. Has anyone tried this?

http://libcloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/compute/drivers/vcloud.html

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver

import libcloud.security  

def testConnection():
    #libcloud.security.VERIFY_SSL_CERT = True
    vcloud = get_driver(Provider.VCLOUD)
    driver = vcloud("user@org", "xxxxx", host='portal.local', api_version='5.1')   

    nodes = driver.list_nodes()    
    for i in nodes:
        print i      
    images = driver.list_images()    
    image = [i for i in images if i.name == "New Base VM vApp"][0]
    print image   

    locations = driver.list_locations()
    print locations

    vdcs = driver.vdcs
    vdc = [i for i in vdcs if "VDC_NAME" in i.name ][0]    
    for i in vdcs:
        if "VDC_NAME" in i.name:
            print "VDC\n"
            print i
            dev_test_vdc = i.name
            print i    
    print "creating node"
    node = driver.create_node(name="test_vAPP", image=image,  ex_vdc=dev_test_vdc, ex_clone_timeout=500)

def main():
    testConnection()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As a contributor to vCloud driver in libcloud I'm afraid that there is no support for this. vApps are there mapped to VMs in 1:1 manner. You can read the implementation of method create_node at [github](https://github.com/apache/libcloud/blob/trunk/libcloud/compute/drivers/vcloud.py)

However you can [contribute](https://libcloud.apache.org/community.html#contributing) such functionality.